# Assignment as part of ternary if

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I found the following snippet in our code base. This is code that is widely used and hasn't caused any issues, and I can't figure out why.

```
element = someBoolean ?
            element = parentElement :
            element;
```

Shouldn't the second line be resetting `element` to an empty value or something after it is set to `parentElement`

ETA: I am wondering what the return value of the `element = parentElement` clause would be because it didn't seem like there was any return value over there. I forgot that there is a concept of multiple assignments in java, so element would just be set twice.

Comment: What do you mean by _empty value_? And what makes you think that should happen? Depending on your real code, this `element = parentElement:` might be completely redundant. Just use `parentElement` in the ternary, no need for the assignment.

Comment: If `someBoolean` is true, then the code is `element = element = parentElement`, which, while redundant, should work.

Comment: I don't know what I mean by empty value. I am wondering what the assignment that happens in the if-true part of the ternary is if there is an assignment. 
I know that this code is incorrect. I am trying to figure out why it seems to have been working the way I expected before I noticed this bug.

Comment: I understand now. I was confused about the result of "element = parentElement". I thought it would return void or something, forgetting that you can have multiple assignments in java like "a = b = c" where a and b are both set to c.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Shouldn't the second line be resetting element to an empty value or
>   something after it is set to parentElement

I don't know why you would think that. The purpose of the entire statement is to potentially reassign `element` to `parentElement`. The statement is equivalent to:

```
element = someBoolean ?
            parentElement:
            element;
```

This is because an assignment statement (`element = parentElement`) has a value of the RHS (i.e. `parentElement`). I would simply write it this way, though:

```
if (someBoolean) {
    element = parentElement;
}
```

Comment: You're right - this is really bad code :( I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The assignment is quite useless, since your code can be written as...

```
element = someBoolean ?
            parentElement:
            element;
```

Only in your code, you do not return `parentElement` immediately, but first set `element` to `parentElement` and then `element` to `element`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand it. I forgot that java allows multiple assignments.